# Design pattern for multiple file JavaScript library that can be used in browser and with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I'm have written a library which primarily made to be used in the browser. Now I want to use this library with node.js too.

My library consists of multiple files like:

loremIpsum.core.js:

```
loremIpsum = {};

loremIpsum.a = function(){
   //Important code
}

loremIpsum.b = function(){
   //Important code
}
```

Then there are other files which are dependent on the `loremIpsum` because they have to use the `a` or `b` function. Like:

loremIpsum.dolor.js:

```
loremIpsum.dolor = loremIpsum.a(); 

loremIpsum.dolor.x = function(){
   //Important code
}

loremIpsum.dolor.y = function(){
   //Important code
}
```

I have no idea how I could use that code with node.js. When I would require the files like: (pretending I've assigned `exports` to `loremIpsum`)

```
var loremIpsum = require("loremIpsum.core.js");
require("loremIpsum.dolor.js");
```

The problem is that `loremIpsum.dolor.js` would not work because `loremIpsum` is not defined.

I've read about some libraries and requireJS but I would prefer not to use such a library. Is there any good approach?

Comment: i suggest reading this http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: @lombausch I think I know how modules work. That's not my problem.

Comment: so if you know than why do you ask? rewrite you library as node module

Comment: @lombausch you didn't get the point of the question: I want be able to use the files in the browser and with node. Without rewriting it. Please consider reading questions first

Comment: It is hard to tell you anything without the actual code. There are some substantial differences how dependencies are defined on server and in browser. I would not advise having large amount of small files in browser as requesting each means another http call to server. I would compile the code into one file for the browser and minify it.

Comment: @lombausch thanks for your help. I've found a solution. (Basically what I've posted above)