# How to import JavaScript functions across files in manner that is simultaneously compatible with Node.js and with browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In vanilla browser-based JavaScript, I can do this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then:

```
// file1.js

function abc(foo) {
    console.log("abc received:", foo);
}
```

And:

```
// file2.js

abc(36);
```

...and things behave as expected. (I.e., "abc received 36" is printed to the console.)

How can I include functions from `file1.js` in `file2.js` in node.js, so as to preserve the functionality above, while also keeping the web page as-is? Specifically, I would like to keep the html as it appears above, while being able to run

```
node file2.js
```

at the command line, and getting `abc received 36` at the terminal.

### Edit

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958208/design-pattern-for-multiple-file-javascript-library-that-can-be-used-in-browser) question with a very similar motivation, by a seemingly more advanced user. But the main link in the answer to that question is dead, and I don't understand how the stated answer works, or what it's supposed to do. Maybe someone can provide me with a MWE tailored to my `file1.js`, `file2.js`?

Comment: Use ES6 modules. They're supported both by latest node.js and browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for scripts to be functional as both Node.js modules and browser vanilla (non-modular) scripts, they should be defined as [UMD modules](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

UMD is basically a boilerplate factory function that detects modular environment and falls back to global variables if needed.

E.g. for CommonJS and globals (no AMD) the definition would be:

*file1.js*

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof exports.nodeName !== 'string') {
        // Node
        module.exports = factory();
        // Global
    } else {
        root.file1 = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {
    // module body
    function abc(foo) {
        console.log("abc received:", foo);
    }

    return { abc: abc };
}));
```

*file2.js*

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof exports.nodeName !== 'string') {
        // Node
        module.exports = factory(require('./file1'));
        // Global
    } else {
        root.file2 = factory(root.file1);
    }
}(this, function (file1) {
    // module body
    file1.abc(36);
}));
```

Omitting this boilerplate is the task that bundling tools are supposed to solve, notably Browserify that is intended specifically to bundle CommonJS modules to browser scripts.

Comment: What if  `file1` contains several functions, plus a declaration like `const sin = Math.sin`? And if several different `file`s are to be imported from file2? (I'm sorry but it's not obvious to me how to generalize the syntax :/, I'm very lost and don't understand what's going on.)

Comment: Then the question should contain your real requirements. The answer is as good as the question is. I've tried to update it. Any way, I'd suggest to stick to Node modules and run them in browser with Browserify. There's no need to have separate files in a browser.

Comment: Yes my bad. Your update answers the "several functions" question but not the "several files to import" question. Is that not possible with this approach? (I think that in the meanwhile I'm just going to be copy-pasting my code around, actually. No time to learn Browserify before deadline.)

Comment: You will need to pass several dependencies like `factory(require('./file1'), require('./file3'))`,  `factory(root.file1, root.file3)`, `function (file1, file3) {`, etc. It's extremely simple pattern. There's a function. Dependencies should be passed to it as a parameters. And there's actually nothing to learn regarding Browserify, it's `browserify node-entry-script.js > browser-output.js`. You will waste much more time on reinventing the wheel with module wrappers.